# Laravel 5.2: Class Category Not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I want to make a dropdownlist in laravel 5.2 application.And i want to load the category Item in my view page .But while i load the page it's showing the following Error.

> FatalErrorException in routes.php line 47: Class 'Category' not found

If anyone know what's the problem, pleas help me to finish it.

Here is My Category Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model{
     protected $table="categories";

    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

Here is the routes:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {

    $categories=Category::all();
    return view('index')->with ('categories',$categories);

});
```

And here is the view page if it's required:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cascading Dropwon</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h3>Categories and Subcategories Ajax</h3>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                {!! Form::open(array('url' => '','files'=>true))  !!}
                {!! Form::token(); !!}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Categories</label>
                        <select class="form-control input-sm" name="">
                        @foreach($categories as $category){
                        <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
                        }
                        @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Sub Categories</label>
                        <select class="form-control input-sm" name="">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>


                {!!Form::close()!!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you try `composer dump-autoload` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not namespacing your Model(Category) in your route.
Change it to

```
 Route::get('/', function () {

   $categories=\App\Category::all();
   return view('index')->with ('categories',$categories);

});
```

Comment: thanks..it's worked. But can you tell me why we need to add \App\Category ?

Comment: Because Category is in the App namspace (App\Category) and you are referencing it from App\Http\Controllers namespace which does not exist.